# Programmatically scroll RecyclerView with disabled vertical scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerView has ViewPagers and buttons within it, so I cannot disable scrolling or disable all touches.

I disable only vertical scrolling with:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem is when I try to scroll the recyclerView with code:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, 500);
```

The smoothScrollBy in android is defined as:

```
public void smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy, Interpolator interpolator) {
    if (mLayout == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot smooth scroll without a LayoutManager set. "
                + "Call setLayoutManager with a non-null argument.");
        return;
    }
    if (mLayoutFrozen) {
        return;
    }
    if (!mLayout.canScrollHorizontally()) {
        dx = 0;
    }
    if (!mLayout.canScrollVertically()) { // <--- problem
        dy = 0;
    }
    if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
        mViewFlinger.smoothScrollBy(dx, dy, interpolator);
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when I call scrollBy or smoothScrollBy because canScrollVertically is false.

Also note that if I set it to true, then scroll, then try to false, the scrollView jitters and it does not scroll completely:

```
layoutManager.canScrollVertically = true;
recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, 500);
layoutManager.canScrollVertically = false; // -> when this line is set, the smoothScrolling stops immediately
```

I am trying to prevent the user from scrolling vertically, because I am trying to handle the vertical scrolling from code. The user should still be able to interact with other elements within the RecyclerView and be able to scroll horizontally within the RecyclerView.

What can I try?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GestureDetector to make this, look at code below. Method `onScroll()` should return true, and that is important part of this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Random random = (new Random());
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String s[] = {"One","One2","One3","One4","One5","One6","One7","One8","One9","One10","One11","One12","One13","One14","One","One2","One3","One4","One5","One6","One7","One8","One9","One10","One11","One12","One13","One14"};
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(s));
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
//                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void scrollClicked(View v) {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
        return false;
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private String[] mDataset;

        // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
        // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
        // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            // each data item is just a string in this case
            public TextView mTextView;
            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                mTextView = (TextView) v;
            }
        }

        // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
        public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
            mDataset = myDataset;
        }

        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {
            // create a new view
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            // - get element from your dataset at this position
            // - replace the contents of the view with that element
            holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

        }

        // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDataset.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To create Horizontal RecyclerView use this code:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Nah that just makes my recyclerView into a horizontal list. I need a vertical list that can't be scrolled by the user but can be scroll with code.